# How to determine the frame of a UIView within the root view when using Auto Layout?

Tags: swift

I have a `UIView` that I have placed within the window view using `auto layout`.  However, when i tried to print out the frame of the `UIView` in the console I am getting back zero.  How does one go about determining the location of the `UIView`?

The reason I would like to know the frame is because I would like to use the following functions when displaying mutiple UIViews

`func intersects(CGRect) -> Bool` Returns whether two rectangles intersect.

`func contains(CGRect) -> Bool` Returns whether the first rectangle contains the second rectangle.

```
 var margin: UILayoutGuide!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    margin = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide

    let sq1 = Square.init(color: UIColor.blue)
    self.view.addSubview(sq1)

    sq1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sq1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    sq1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    sq1.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: margin.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    sq1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    print("sq1.frame: \(sq1.frame)")
}


 class Square: UIView{

var colour: UIColor

init(color: UIColor) {
    self.colour = color
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.backgroundColor = color
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
sq1.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the vc use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidlayoutSubviews()
      print("sq1.frame: \(sq1.frame)")
}
```

Inside the view's class

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
      print("self.frame: \(self.frame)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to wait until `layoutSubviews()` is called. You can use code similar to this:

```swift
 class Square: UIView{

    let colour: UIColor

    init(color: UIColor) {
        self.colour = color
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("frame: \(frame)")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```